# adding custom classes for tables

Tags: functions, customization

I have to implement a default class for HTML-Tables at WordPress. The wp-standard is `<table>`

.. ist there any way to do this, that i get this output per default? `<table class="abc xyz">`

maybe with filters?

Comment: What table are you taking about?

Comment: normal html table ... `<table></table>`. I want to add a class autmatically so i dont have to do this at every post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you need to add  custom hook for `the_content` filter:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse8170_add_custom_table_class' );
function wpse8170_add_custom_table_class( $content ) {
    return str_replace( '<table>', '<table class="mycustom-class">', $content );
}
```

Add this snippet to your `functions.php` file.

Answer (score 2):

I made a simple modification to get the code recognize other styles within the  tag:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse8170_add_custom_table_class' );
function wpse8170_add_custom_table_class( $content ) {
return str_replace( '<table', '<table class="my-class"', $content );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no table functionality in the default editors, visual or text, so unless are using an editor like `CKEditor` that does generate that markup, I'd use a shortcode.

```
function table_wrapper_wpse_114253( $atts, $content = null ) {
  return '<table class="abc xyz">'.$content.'</table>';
}
add_shortcode('table','table_wrapper_wpse_114253');
```

In your content, just write `[table]...[/table]` instead of `<table>...</table>`

I have to add that if your theme uses [`body_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) and [`post_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) correctly, and all you want to do is add a class to *every* `<table>` in the post body, there is almost certainly existing markup in place that makes what you are doing unnecessary, whether you use a filter on `the_content` as @EugeneManuilov suggests or a shortcode.